# Sending a message to all other instances of the application on the same network

Tags: c++, boost, multicast

How do I send a message using multicast on the same network ?

I am using C++, with the library boost. I have played around with the sender and receiver example.

But I also have a few questions, I am new to networks and C++.
The multicast port is set to 30001, is there any good reason for this ?

The examples suggests that I use, for the sender:

> IPv4 239.255.0.1
>
> IPV6 ff31::8000:1234

And for the receiver:

> IPv4 0.0.0.0 239.255.0.1
>
> IPv6 0::0 ff31::8000:1234

Why those specific addresses ?

Also in the receiver example, there is a section dedicated to joining the multicast address, is there a way to check if a new connection has showed up on this address ? to see what new instance joins or leaves the connection, is this possible ?

But my main question is, if I were to send a message like Hello World from my computer running the example, would this show up on another computer on the same network ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why those specific addresses ?

Those are the addresses specified by the IP protocol (IPv4/IPv6) for multicasting. Part of the addresses are groups specifications (I think 255.0.1 for IPv4 and 1234 for IPv6). The traffic is forwarded to specific ports on local machine, but I don't know/can't find details.

> Also in the receiver example, there is a section dedicated to joining the multicast address, is there a way to check if a new connection has showed up on this address ? to see what new instance joins or leaves the connection, is this possible ?

No, there's no builtin capability like that. Multicast is supposed to be sent to at least all interested machines. The joining is a signal to the network/local OS that you are an interested machine and that it should pickup and forward relevant packets. There's no need to forward such signals in all cases (i.e. if the router already has the packets).

You can however broadcast your presence on the channel after you joined, but that's part of the protocol you want to implement on top of multicasting.

> But my main question is, if I were to send a message like Hello World from my computer running the example, would this show up on another computer on the same network ?

Depends. If you're wired into the same layer 1 (direct Ethernet or direct WiFi) fabric, then probably yes. If you have to hop through a router/access point they might have firewall rules that inhibit the traffic.

See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast) for a summary of how it works. Or read the [rfc1112](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1112), [rfc4604](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4604) and [rfc5771](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5771) for the standard.

Comment: Thank you. but when you mentioned that I could broadcast my presence, what do you mean by that ? and how would I do so ?

Comment: You send a message to the broadcast group. Any machine on the network can do it.